# EntityFramework (database first) using Azure managed identity for SQL DB

Tags: entity-framework-6, azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity

I'm in the process of converting the existing .Net framework project that uses EF 6 with Database First approach (EDMX) file to .Net Standard 2.1 which connects to SQLDB hosted on Azure.

Existing EDMX file has a constructor (auto generated) that accepts ConnectionString as given below -

```
 public TestDatabaseConnection()
        : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabaseConnection"].ConnectionString)
    {
    }
```

This is breaking for two reasons -

1. ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings works only in .Net framework projects and throw runtime errors in the .Net Core project (for eg- ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings returns null).
2. I need to make changes to the above code to use the AppAuthentication nuget as mentioned in the MSDN docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi#modify-your-project)

So, what are the options available in order to make this work so that I could use the same nuget package for connecting to the database via EF 6 (database first) for both .net framework and .net core projects?

Is the only available is to convert to Code first and make the necessary changes as mentioned in the above MSDN link?

Comment: Can you give demo code without sensitive info ?

Comment: @sai did you get any solution for this?

Comment: yes, I have added a second constructor that accepts Connectionstring as parameter. For all .net core that use nuget passes connectionstring in the constructor. For any other full .net framework projects it could continue to use the existing constructor